# How do I format and insert these JSON variables into Mongodb so they can be accessed with jQuery/AJAX/PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, mongodb

I have a huge javascript file that reads sort of like this:

```
var MyVariable1 = [ { 
  ThingsToGet: [ 
  { 
     first_thing: "SOMETHING ONE",
     second_thing: [[1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 4], [4, 4], [5, "x"], [6, "x"]]
     third_thing: 0,
     fourth_thing: []
     },{ 
     first_thing: "SOMETHING TWO",
     second_thing: [[1, 0], [2, 5], [3, 4], [4, 4], [5, "x"], [6, "x"]],
     third_thing: 0,
     fourth_thing: []
     },{ 
     first_thing: "SOMETHING THREE",
     second_thing: [[1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 4], [4, 4], [5, 2], [6, 2]],
     third_thing: 0,
     fourth_thing: []
     },
   ]
   }
 ];


 var MyVariable2 = [ { 
     ThingsToGet: [ etc, etc, etc...
```

I'd like to shove all of that into a MongoDB database and have the client just grab the variables he/she needs via AJAX so they won't have to download the whole file. An additional reason is the data in the file is also semi-sensitive so it would also be nice if it couldn't be downloaded directly.

Just to make it a little harder, I also need to use Underscore.js to combine the 'MyVariables' like so:

```
var CombinedVariables = _.union(MyVariable1, MyVariable2);
```

I've seen this example:  http://media.mongodb.org/zips.json  but I don't know if in my case whether each 'MyVariable' variable should be a separate document or collection or what.

And as I'm typing this I'm starting to wonder if this is possible at all, it would have to work like this:

```
var CombinedVariables = _.union(MyVariable1, MyVariable2);  
//both variables are stored in mongo, keep in mind there are thousands of them


 for (var i = 0; i < CombinedVariables.length; ++i) { blah blah blah };
//we do some things with each variable
```

Somewhere in there would have to be an Ajax function to get the variables, but I'm not sure where and I'm not even sure if it's possible to do it that way.

So to sum up: I'm new to JSON, AJAX & MongoDB, I don't know how to format the JSON, I don't know how to fetch the variables and I don't know if this is possible or even worth trying.

ps I'm using PHP server-side, possibly with this Mongo REST server thing which looks interesting:  https://github.com/joevallender/slim-php-mongo-rest

Comment: " I also need to use Underscore.js to combine the 'MyVariables'" no you don't. That's what you're doing right now, but it's an artificial need. I'd recommend starting small, and seeing if you can set up mongo to accept a single record like the one you're trying to store, and then getting it back out. If you can do that (which is entirely doable) then you can put it more records, and merge them however you need to (likely, not using underscore's union. Mongo can already do findAlls)

Comment: What is the expected query pattern? Will users be selecting documents only by the "MyVariable" number (whether a single number or multiple, via some `or` logic)? Will you ever need to query by the fields of the objects within the ThignsToGet arrays?

Comment: I ended up doing what 'Pomax' suggested, skipping Underscore's Union and using a PHP script to combine the variables the way I wanted and putting them in separate Mongo collections.  Now when I need 'CombinedVariables' I just grab the whole collection.